# How to translate "x has been added to your Wish List. Click here to continue shopping."

Tags: magento2

The string "x has been added to your Wish List. Click here to continue shopping." can be found in the template Magento/Wishlist/view/frontend/templates/messages/addProductSuccessMessage.phtml

But it doesn't the usual pattern

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Some string you can translate') ?>
```

What should I write in my csv file?

Below the template file

```
<?php
echo $block
    ->escapeHtml(
        $block->getData('product_name')
    )
?> has been added to your Wish List. Click <a href="<?php
echo $block
    ->escapeUrl(
        $block->getData('referer')
    )
?>">here</a> to continue shopping.
```

**edit 02.09.2019**

Since the question was asked, the template file has been updated to be translatable https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/624173e59cdbb5f4203ce346b1b53637f32672ef#diff-7586a821ac9c752c277b0c4304885b76

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use sprintf to pass in the dynamic details then you can use the formatting string to do translation.

Example:

`$message = sprintf("%s has been added to your cart.", $product->getName());`

Then in your csv you would just include: 
`%s has been added to your cart.` And then translate to whatever language you require, keeping the %s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read in an article that Magento 2 translations were not sprintf compatible. But I'll take your suggestion and override the template file. http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/137168044820/magento-2-translation-function-not-sprintf

Comment: @csmarvz if you satisfied with the answer, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

According official documentation about [translation in Magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html) you should create a dictionnary CSV file in your theme folder.

> app/design/frontend/Magento/demo/i18n/fr_FR.csv

```
"%1 has been added to your Wish List. Click here to continue shopping.","%1 a été ajouté à votre liste de favoris"
```

> Any PHP file

```
$messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('%1 has been added to your Wish List. Click here to continue shopping.', $product->getName()));
```